# Python - MySQL connection error

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I use Python 3.5.2 and PyMySQL

and after creating  the database of MySQL

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql(host='127.0.0.1',unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock',user='root',passwd=None,db='mysql')
```

> AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

p.s. when setting MySQL in my win10,the port 3306 can't work(make me unable to continue)

so I change the port to 306 and then work

Has that any impact on my error?

it shows some error...

Comment: Why do you connect through the socket, not through the port?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on Windows, you cannot use a Unix socket to connect to the database.  When connecting, set the host and port parameters instead of unix_socket.

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='Your password', db='mysql')
```